# Crystal Report icons/toolbar not working when deployed on web server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, crystal-reports

I have built a web page which contains a Crystal Report built using the Crystal libraries included in Visual Studio 2008.

It '[works on my machine](http://jcooney.net/archive/2007/02/01/42999.aspx)' but when deployed to the web server the icons (Export, Print etc) on the Crystal Report toolbar do not display or work.  Just seeing the 'red X' where the button image should be and clicking does nothing.

I have checked that the toolbar images are actually in the location being looked at on the web server:
(C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/images/toolbar/)
They are all there.

I have checked the permissions on the above mentioned folder on the web server.
Gave 'full control' to every user just to test it.

I have also intalled/run the 'CRRedist2008_x86.msi' on the web server.

Some people have mentioned ensuring that 'crystalreportviewers115' folder is added to my '\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727' folder on the web server but I have been unable to find the 'crystalreportviewers115' to copy it.

Appreciate any help or ideas you may be able to offer.

Update - OK, so obviously I hadn't checked well enough that the images were in the correct location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doh! Someone else here at work figured this out.  It was really simple and I should have been able to sort it, but hey, that's how it goes sometimes.

Here the fix:
On the web server, copy the 'aspnet_client' folder from 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot' to 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\your-website-name'.

That's all we did and it's now working.

Hope this saves someone from all the fuss I just went through.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to simply create a new virtual directory in your web site and point it to "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/aspnet_client"

Answer (score 2):

Try this
On the web server, copy the 'aspnet_client' folder from 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot'  and past inside your website folder.(where form folder,app_data folder etc will be there)

Answer (score 0):

I took over maintaining some code produced by another developer who had left and suffered this issue too. In my case the compiled report was looking for the images in the crystalreportview115 folder which existed in my local development path and therefore worked locally. The only folder on on the target server was the CrystalReportWebFormViewer4 (I assume from a previous server installation or site deployment). Simply adding the ...115 folder sorted the problem out for me.

The root cause for us would appear to be the version of Crystal installed on the developers machine. Not sure that helps anyone but thought I'd mention it!

Answer (score 0):

Upload aspnet_client folder from c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder of your local computer to the httpdocs folder of your web hosting server. Good Luck!!!