# crystal report viewer next page not working

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2010 and crystal report 13.0

The report viewer displays the first page properly. But the next page button is not working. If i click on next page button then it shows loading message and stays there only.None of the report viewer controls are working.

please help me out

Comment: is this happening on local machine or server. You could have a look at the following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347/crystal-report-icons-toolbar-not-working-when-deployed-on-web-server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution.
Manually add the `Page_Init()` event and wire it up in the `InitializeCompnent()` with

`this.Init += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Init).`

Move the contents of `Page_Load` to `Page_Init()`.

Add `if (!IsPostBack)` condition in `PageInIt`.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             ReportDocument crystalReportDocument = new ReportDocumment();
             crystalReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTableHere);
             _reportViewer.ReportSource = crystalReportDocument;
             Session["ReportDocument"] = crystalReportDocument;
        }
        else
        {
              ReportDocument doc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];
              _reportViewer.ReportSource = doc;
        }
   }
```

Comment: this is the solution that i needed so bad! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually identifying the moment to bind, you could use the CrystalReportViewer AutoDataBind property in combination with the DataBinding event.

Autobind definition:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Boolean. Gets or sets whether automatic data binding to a report source is
    //     used. If the value is set to True, the DataBind() method is called after
    //     OnInit() or Page_Init().
    [Category("Data")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool AutoDataBind { get; set; }
```

You could use this property in the following manner:

In the ASPX:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="_reportViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" OnDataBinding="_reportViewer_DataBinding" />
```

And in the ASPX.CS:

```
protected void _reportViewer_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReportDocument = new ReportDocumment();
        crystalReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTableHere);
        _reportViewer.ReportSource = crystalReportDocument;
        Session["ReportDocument"] = crystalReportDocument;
    }
    else
    {
        ReportDocument doc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];
        _reportViewer.ReportSource = doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if two reports are being viewed at the same time then how would i differenciate between two different report documents?

Comment: To view two reports at the same time you will probably have two ReportViewer controls. This gives you the ability to define two DataBinding event handler methods. These methods effectively enable you to select the proper datasource for the report.
Spider man uses the session. You could use that to store another object. Nothing however stops you from querying the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

> Done! Shift your Page load Event to Page Init Event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (IsPostBack)
     {
           int pageIndex =((CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRequestContext)  
            CrystalReportViewer1.RequestContext).PageNumber;

           //Bind Report with filter and datasource

           string ControID = GetPostBackControlName(this);
          //get and check Crystal Report Navigation button event after Bind Report

           if (ControID == null)
           {  
              ((CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRequestContext)
              CrystalReportViewer1.RequestContext).PageNumber = pageIndex;      
            }
      }
 }

 public string GetPostBackControlName(Page Page)
    {
        Control control = null;

        string ctrlname = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
        {
            control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }
        else
        {
            string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
            Control c = null;
            foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
            {
                if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
                {
                    ctrlStr = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                    c = Page.FindControl(ctrlStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    c = Page.FindControl(ctl);
                }
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||
                         c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (control == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return control.ID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a code-only answer, which is not considered good quality in SO. Please add explanation and elaborate what this code does and why it helps to solve the issue.

Comment: As Page_Load even, after report bind will reset the crystal report page index to 1 we have to maintain it before and after Bind the report while navigation.